# How create or generate the channelTx and Genesisblock

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

> I am using the configTx to create the channelTx and genesis block,
>   using the config-file.yaml.

- Is there is any other way to create the channelTx and genesisTx using fabric-sdk-node ?
- when the fabric network setup and running are it possible to update the channelTx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question, as many wants to know the answer to this question

Let me first talk about hyperledger fabric tools

- cryptogen
- configtxgen
- configtxlator
- protolator
- idemixgen

Link here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.4/common/tools

These tools are opensource and built by IBM, fabric team, aims to fulfill configuration tasks. `As of now 1.4 SDK's doesn't support for configuration tasks`

Each & every tool is built by golang and make use of grpc

**Coming to your second question**:

Once the channel is created then no use of channel.tx file if you want to update you will have to send update transaction

Comment: means,At start i have to use the configtxgen to create the genesis and channelTx